# How can I run multiple Intern processes on same machine?

Tags: intern

How do I run multiple Intern processes concurrently on the same machine?

Comment: `tunnelOptions.port` sets the port that Selenium listens on (via Selenium's `-port` argument), and setting that + `serverPort` and `socketPort` should be sufficient. Are you seeing a specific error?

Comment: Hmm, I guess you are right!  It wasn't working for me last week but now it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the serverPort, socketPort, and tunnelOptions.port properties to unique values for each Intern process.

This will override Intern's 4444, 9000, and 9001 default port settings.